# Error 13 permission denied when run buildozer

Tags: python, android, permissions, kivy

When I run buildozer android debug command in ubuntu app in windows[wsl] this error occurred and stuck in here.please help me to solve this.

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):

>File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer",line 11, in <module>
>     load_entry_point('buildozer==1.2.0.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.2.0.dev0 py3.8.egg/buildozer/scripts/client.py",
 line 13, in main
>     Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.2.0.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/__init__.py",
> line 1004, in run_command
>     self.target.run_commands(args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.2.0.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands
>     func(args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.2.0.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 104, in cmd_debug
>     self.buildozer.build()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.2.0.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/__init__.py",
> line 202, in build
>     self.build_application()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.2.0.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/__init__.py",
> line 683, in build_application
>     self._copy_application_libs()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/buildozer-1.2.0.dev0-py3.8.egg/buildozer/__init__.py",
> line 782, in _copy_application_libs
>     copytree(self.applibs_dir, join(self.app_dir, '_applibs'))   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 554, in copytree
>     return _copytree(entries=entries, src=src, dst=dst, symlinks=symlinks,   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 510, in
> _copytree
>     raise Error(errors) shutil.Error: [('/mnt/e/kivyExperiment/.buildozer/applibs',
> '/mnt/e/kivyExperiment/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs', "[Errno 13]
> Permission denied:
> '/mnt/e/kivyExperiment/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs'")]
```

Comment: `Permission denied` in error message may means that you have to run it as `root` - ie. `sudo your_command`.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using WSL and your project is in the Windows folder, than there is an incompatibility between Windows file permissions and Linux file permissions.
For your case the answer is here https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1108#issuecomment-684964068 (move your project to a directory relative to the WSL home, for example `~/yourProject`).

Answer (score 1):

Just grant full control access to folder E:\kivyExperiment\ at Windows to your current Windows user.

[image: permissions]

If your "WindowsUsername" is not listed in your folder properties, click Edit button and add it first.